# modal pop up with a repeater in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a repeater in aspx. Inside my item template, I have two "items" that are populating. one is a label, and one is a pop up modal that connects to that label. I databind it with a data adapter in the backend.

Lets say I searched for something, and 10 labels populated dynamically. I want to click on each individual one and have a pop up modal that populates the same data of the label I just clicked on.

How do you connect the data from the label to the pop up modal? 
when I click on each label, the data that populates in the pop up modal is the same as the first data from the first label that populated.

i see this all the time in shopping websites... i just can't figure out another way to dynamically make this label without a repeater. help please!
thank you.

Comment: Without seeing your code we can only guess what you are trying to do and what is wrong with your code. Can you share your code please?

Comment: I will recommend you to use GridView. As I've faced same problem (popup bootstrap model when click on each row or label) and solved as like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409549/popup-bootstrap-model-on-gridview-edit-click-using-rowcommand-event

Comment: @Asif.Ali I don't want to use gridview because it doesn't display the results as nice as I would like it to..