# Pop-up Modal on View button from GridView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, bootstrap-modal

I have a grid with recordds being retrieved from a database. As part of my grid I have a View button.
When I click on the View link button I want a pop up to open which will be displaying the records in a form.

My problem is that when I click on the View link  button the pop up modal does not open.

This is what I have so far

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >

        <div class="grid">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfUserID" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddUser" runat="server" Text="Add New User" OnClick="btnAddUser_Click" />
            <asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server"  PagerStyle-CssClass="pager"
                HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" 

                CssClass="mydatagrid" AllowPaging="True" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3">
                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
                <Columns>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserID">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' runat="server"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>'  runat="server"/>
                         </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsernameFooter"  runat="server"/>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>' runat="server"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>'  runat="server"/>
                         </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsernameFooter"  runat="server"/>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Password") %>' runat="server"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" Text='<%# Eval("Password") %>'  runat="server"/>
                         </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPasswordFooter"  runat="server"/>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>' runat="server"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>'  runat="server"/>
                         </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailFooter"  runat="server"/>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" style="color:pink" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UserID")%>'  OnClick="lnk_OnClick">View </asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            </div>
    </form>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

    <script>


        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');


        var btn = document.getElementById("lnkView");


        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


        btn.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }


        span.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }



</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Popup bootstrap model on GridView edit click using RowCommand event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409549/popup-bootstrap-model-on-gridview-edit-click-using-rowcommand-event)

Answer (score 0):

The LinkButton control causes a postback via javascript, and subsequently a server side click event.  The postback is probably what is causing the problem.

I would recommend trying a plain HTML `<a>` element in your ItemTemplate, or `<asp:HyperLink>` if you need to manipulate it server side (as well as firing the client click event handler).

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has an api for that. You don't need to programatically open it with the event handler. Add `data-toggle` to your buttons. And then attach the modal id to the `href` tag of that button. And, change your `LinkButton` to a regular `a` tag:

```
<a style="color:pink" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">View</a>
```

Then, to close it, attach the same attributes to your close button:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
      <a class="btn btn-default prev pull-left" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Cancel</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the bigger problem is use of the LinkButton control.

Comment: Good point. It's easier to prevent a post-back with a link button. I have updated.

Comment: It tries to open the following: http://localhost:50598/AddUser.aspx#myModal

Still does not work

Comment: Are you still using `LinkButton`, or did you change it to `Hyperlink`?

Comment: I did change it to HyperLink. I copied exactly what you provided

Comment: Well, whether you use a `LinkButton` or a `Hyperlink`, the goal is to get the element rendered something like this: `<a style="color:pink" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">View</a>`. I must not remember correctly how those asp controls handle clicks and post backs. Check my updated answer, and just use an `a` tag.

Comment: There's a good chance HyperLink did not pass through some of the attributes such as `data-toggle`.  Try `<a>`