# How to populate bootstrap modal using c# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, repeater, bootstrap-popover

I created a repeater control which displays data from the database. When the user click delete button it should fetch the respective column data from database and store it in the fields which is actually not happening.

I attached my entire code with this question.

Anyone please help me!

All other solutions available are based on only jQuery. But I want to do it through c#.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Repeater.aspx.cs" Inherits="intern4.Repeater" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="repeaterstylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
        <div>

            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"  >
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <div class="container align" >
                        <div class="row header">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">ID</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">Name</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">Class</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">Edit</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">Delete</div>
                        </div>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="row data">
                        <div class="col-sm-2"> <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentID") %>' /></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2"><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentName") %>' /></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2"><asp:Label ID="lblClassx" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentClass") %>' /></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="StudEdit.aspx?ID= <%# Eval("StudentID") %>">Edit</a></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbtn" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="btn btn-primary" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" 
                                data-toggle="modal" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("StudentID") %>' OnCommand="btn_clck" >
                                Delete
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <hr style="color:blue" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </div>
                </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Conformation alert</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">ID</legend>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="form-check">
                           <asp:label id="lblStudentID" runat="server" class="form-check-label" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <asp:TextBox ID="inputName" runat="server" class="form-control"  Text=""></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputClass" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Class</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <asp:TextBox  ID="inputClass" runat="server" class="form-control" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="yes" OnClick="Deletestudent" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace intern4
{
    public partial class Repeater : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.BindRepeater();
            }
        }

        private void BindRepeater()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT StudentID, StudentName, StudentClass FROM tbl_Student", con))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
                            Repeater1.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Deletestudent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int studentId = int.Parse(((sender as Button).NamingContainer.FindControl("lblId") as Label).Text);
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tbl_Student WHERE StudentID = @StudentId", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentId", studentId);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            this.BindRepeater();
        }
        protected void btn_clck(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int s = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
            lblStudentID.Text = s.ToString();
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
                con.Open();
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                   "select * from tbl_Student where StudentID=" + s + "", con);
                    SqlDataReader sd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (sd.Read())
                    {
                        inputName.Text = sd.GetValue(1).ToString();
                        inputClass.Text = sd.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {

                }
                con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46410815/5377037) you have to add below code after setting the `TextBox` Controls:

```
//... Some other code

while (sd.Read()) {
  inputName.Text = sd.GetValue(1).ToString();
  inputClass.Text = sd.GetValue(2).ToString();
}

System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
sb.Append("$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');");
sb.Append(@"</script>");
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "MyModel", 
sb.ToString(), false);
```

This code will populate the Bootstrap Model from C# code-behind.